# Laravel Eloquent activity feed

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to create a simple activity feed where a user can see his friends' updates.

I'm dealing with three tables. user_status, friendship and users.

> users table

```
user_id
name
email
..(a regular users table, nothing special)
```

> friendship table

```
friendship_id
friend_one (Foreign key from users table)
friend_two (Foreign key from users table)
```

> user_status table

```
status_id
user_id (foreign key from users table)
status
date
```

---

MODELS

> User Model

```
public function friends() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'friendship', 'friend_one', 'friend_two');
}

public function status() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\UserStatus','status_id');
    }
```

> UserStatus Model

```
public function usersStatus() {
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User','user_id');
}
```

FeedController.php

```
class FeedController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {

        $friends = Auth::user()->friends;


        return view('frontend.feed.index')
          ->with('friends',$friends);
    }

}
```

Using the query below, I can get a user's friends. I also can get a specific user's status updates easily, but I have no idea how to list only specific users' statuses.

```
@foreach($friends as $friend)
    {{$friend->email}}
@endforeach
```

The one below doesn't work.

View

```
@foreach($friends as $friend)
    @foreach($friend->status as $status)
        {{$status->status}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach


Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/master/resources/views/frontend/feed/index.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your foreign_key reference in

```
public function status() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\UserStatus','status_id');
}
```

Change to :

```
public function status() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\UserStatus', 'user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

and it should work.

Comment: It doesn't work, I get the same error. May I ask why there are two user_id's in the relationship?

Comment: Since you're not using default id's you will have to override your local_key and foreign_key references in the format 
$this->hasMany('App\Models\UserStatus, 'foreign_key', 'local_key'). Now since your foreign_key and local_key are both user_id.
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Also why do you have a usersStatus() method in your UserStatus mode. It should be user().